# How to display days in devexpress resource tree

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tree, resources, devexpress

I cannot find how to display "Days" in *ResourceTree Control*(it's a component of scheduler) in devexpress as it is shown in Devexpress documentation: https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument10685

Should I do smth in resourceTree properties or in Scheduler properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `Days` column is existed in the underlying data source which is applied to the `SchedulerStorage.Resources.DataSource` property. So, if you want to show the particular column which is existed in your resources data source then you can add it through designer:
[image: Designer]

Or directly in your code.

```
var colDaysPlanned = new ResourceTreeColumn();

colDaysPlanned.Caption = "Days";
colDaysPlanned.FieldName = "DaysPlanned";
colDaysPlanned.Name = "colDaysPlanned";

resourcesTree1.Columns.Add(colDaysPlanned);
```